# drop down list index always stay at 0

Tags: asp.net, datasource, html-select

I've implemented a drop down list in my webpage and bind it to a data source that I created But no matter what I chose in the page, the `dropdownlist.selectedItem` always get me the first element and `SelectedIndex` is always 0. I've contracted my code with other examples and could not find out why.
here is the code of data source creation and binding:

```
 public void bindLanguage() {  
        DropDownList1.DataSource = CreateDataSource();  
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "language";  
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "value";  
        DropDownList1.DataBind();  
    }  
 public ICollection CreateDataSource()  
    {  
        string[] allLan = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(MyGlobal.LanFile);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("language", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("value", typeof(string)));
        foreach (string lan in allLan)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = lan.Split(',')[0];
            dr[1] = lan.Split(',')[1];
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        return dv;
    }
```

And I call `bindLanguage()` in page_load.
Here's the code in my aspx :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Can you show the code used to check the DropDownlist's selected Index . Also please show the code of Page_Load event. This is where definitely some mistake is done.

Comment: Check if( ! IsPostBack){//your code} in the Page_Load(). Hope it works.

Comment: you are right! i didn't put my method call in if(!IsPostBack){}, and now its working. Thank you for pointing out. Can you write this as an answer so that i can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem .The problem is you are filling your 1st drop-down list in form load and every time some event happens it loads the form i guess u have not kept update panel so again it fills your first drop down and causes selected index changed event to fire which makes your DropDownList1 selected index 0 again and again.

```
    public void bindLanguage() {  
            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
             {
               DropDownList1.DataSource = CreateDataSource();  
               DropDownList1.DataTextField = "language";  
               DropDownList1.DataValueField = "value";  
               DropDownList1.DataBind();  
              }
        }
```

Try this .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add `AutoPostBack="false"` in the markup-code of the DropDownList.

If this ist not set or true, then the page_load will be triggered everytime you change the object in the dropdown list.

this was always a reason for such issues in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Change the AutoPostBack property of the dropdownlist to true. Check if error remains.

Answer (score 0):

add this code **if (IsPostBack) return;** to your Page_Load method.